# Getting variable length paths not involving certain relationships in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know there is a node type `(a:Source)` which will have outgoing edge of type `[:RefRel]` on some other node `(x)`. I want to get all other paths between `(a)` and `(x)` which involve at least one node between them.

Consider my graph is as follows:

[image]

The query should return two paths:`a-b-c-d` and `a-b-c-e`. The nodes and relationships on these path can be of any type.

Creating graph with cypher:

```
CREATE (a:Source)-[:RelA]->(b)-[:RelB]->(c)-[:RelC]->(d)
CREATE (c)-[:RelD]->(e)
CREATE (a)-[:RefRel]->(d)
CREATE (a)-[:RefRel]->(e)
```

I wrote query as follows:

```
MATCH (a:Source)-[:RefRel]-(b)
MATCH path=(a)-[*2..]-(b)      //2.. because that means at least one node on the path
RETURN path
```

But it returned whole graph. When I checked the rows, it returned a lot of them due to cycles in the graph.

So included the filter in the query as follows:

```
MATCH (a:Source)-[:RefRel]-(b)
MATCH path=(a)-[c*2..]-(b)
WHERE filter(rel IN c WHERE rel.name<>"RefRel")
RETURN path
```

But then it returned nothing.
Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the relationships you created have a "name" property. Relationships have types, and this is not a property. You want to use

`type(rel) <> "RefRel"`

Also, on your WHERE, it may be better to use ALL() instead of FILTER().

Comment: ahhh `all()` seems to return two rows, but `filter()` returns a lot of...why?

Comment: filter() does not return a boolean, it returns the filtered collection, so it's not doing what you think it's doing, it's out of place. As far as I can tell, if there's a collection, then it may interpret that as true. By contrast, all() returns a boolean, evaluated to whether the inner WHERE is true for every element in the collection, which is what you were trying to do in the first place.